# Accumulation buffer in OpenGL

Tags: opengl

How to request Accumulation buffer without using glut library on linux platform??

I need an alternative for this API:
    glutInitDisplayMode (GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_ACCUM | GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_MULTISAMPLE);

Comment: What library are you using to create your windows and contexts?

Comment: Not really helpful towards solving your problem, but... note that if you are trying to do _anything_ with an accumulation buffer, you are most likely _"doing it wrong"_. The accumulation buffer is deprecated and is almost guaranteed to absolutely kill your performance.

Comment: @Damon Cards without hardware accumulation support aren't that uncommon are they? I agree, use FBOs if you're planning to release anything. For learning, accumulation is nice and simple to play with.

Answer (score 0):

Not that I've ever done this, but if you're referring to setting up GL yourself with GLX (i.e. as is described here: https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Programming_OpenGL_in_Linux:_GLX_and_Xlib), have a look here: https://www.talisman.org/opengl-1.1/Reference/glXChooseVisual.html

> [glXChooseVisual](https://www.talisman.org/opengl-1.1/Reference/glXChooseVisual.html)
>
> ...
>
> `GLX_ACCUM_RED_SIZE`
> `GLX_ACCUM_GREEN_SIZE`
> `GLX_ACCUM_BLUE_SIZE`
> `GLX_ACCUM_ALPHA_SIZE`
>
> Must be followed by a nonnegative minimum size specification. If this value is zero, visuals with no alpha accumulation buffer are preferred. Otherwise, the largest possible alpha accumulation buffer of at least the minimum size is preferred.

For multisampling, have a look here: https://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/168655-glXChooseFBConfig-multisampling. From [NV_multisample_coverage](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/NV/multisample_coverage.txt), set `GLX_SAMPLE_BUFFERS` and `GLX_SAMPLES`.